# Facing "Internal Server Error" while uploading any file(std functionality)

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller, standard

I am trying to upload a file on an Object(tried all standard & custom Objs) it is failing, facing this issue.
[image]

Even in apex/vf pages where we have used apex:inputfile is failing the same way.

Is this a known issue or something related to specific servers?

Comment: Hi Praveen. Can you confirm if the issue is resolved now. There was salesforce performance degradation for 30 min in some instance. Please find the below url for the same  https://status.salesforce.com/incidents/8571 . if the issue is still not resolved please let me know.

Comment: Yes, It is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in the comment this is due to performance degradation in the instance. The issue is resolved now. Please find the below URL for the same.

[Trust status](https://status.salesforce.com/incidents/8571)